# Combining Array-contains with == in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have documents where I have a map field of teacher containing uid and username and in that same document I have a array field of students that contains the student id's now I want to query documents based on both field how can I merge the code below

```
var teacherRef = db.collection('classes')
                   .where("teacher.id", "==", localStorage.getItem("user"))

var studentRef = db.collection('classes')
                   .where("students", "array-contains", localStorage.getItem("user"))
```

Comment: I want to create a logical OR operation with this two where queries

Comment: I found [this Medium article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d) that might be helpful to you on this concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple `where` in a single query :

```js
var classTeacherRef = db.collection('classes')
    .where("teacher.id", "==", localStorage.getItem("user"))
    .where("students", "array-contains", localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Keep in mind that Firebase will ask you to create index for both properties to make it work.

Comment: This will not solve my problem because it is a logical AND operation with two queries but I want to create a logical OR operation between this two where query.